# HOW CAN I ADD ANY LANGUAGE IN LABELS BY R

Tags: r

HERE I WANT TO PUT IN BENGALI LANGUAGE IN X LABELS AND Y LABELS. HOW CAN I PUT IT?

```
    x<-c(1:10)
    y<-c(1:10)
    plot(x,y,xlabel=" বাংলা   " ,ylabel="বাংলা ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is xlab and ylab:

```
plot(x,y,xlab="বাংল",ylab = "বাংল")
```

[image]